# Is there a way to disable "SpacesInBraces" in clang-format?

Tags: c++, c++11, format, clang, clang-format

I would like this:

```
int x{ 0 };
```

To look like this:

```
int x{0};
```

But I don't see an option for it in [the documentation](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html).

There's:

- SpacesInAngles
- SpacesInContainerLiterals
- SpacesInParentheses
- SpacesInSquareBrackets

But I don't see that option for braces. Is this doable in clang-format?

**EDIT:** The first answer posted uses `Cpp11BracedListStyle`. The problem with that is that it prevents line breaks in arrays. So even 100 elements in a literal array will not have a break. This is too big a side-effect to swallow.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do that with `Cpp11BracedListStyle`.

From the [docs](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html):

> If `true`, format braced lists as best suited for C++11 braced lists.
>
> Important differences:
>
> - **No spaces inside the braced list.**
> - No line break before the closing brace.
> - Indentation with the continuation indent, not with the block indent.

Comment: While this will solve that problem, but this will prevent line brakes completely on array initializations. So even 100 elements will be on the same line.

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist Do you have an example? I'm still getting line breaks.

Comment: Try something like `int x[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,...}` up to a huge number of elements, and it won't break. To be fair, whether `Cpp11BracedListStyle` is true or false, it's not breaking in my case. But I'm assuming `Cpp11BracedListStyle` is partly to blame because it says it won't break in the description you quoted.

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist Cannot reproduce. https://godbolt.org/z/lSAL0z, if I run `clang-format -style=LLVM` on the code on the left, I get the code on the right. You can also use `clang-format` in compiler explorer. Under settings, choose LLVM as style, right-click the left source and press format.

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist And I interpret the description as saying there is no line break between the last element and the closing brace.

Comment: I'm not sure why it's not happening in my code. Seems like something else is causing the problem here.